# Получить количество строк по повторяющейся ячейке с доп данными

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Имеется таблица учета посещений пользователей по сайту:

```
id user  time        link
1  а     01:26:26    /vk 
2  a     01:27:24    /vk
3  b     02:15:24    /vk
4  a     06:21:50    /ok
5  g     03:31:20    /ok
```

Как можно получить такой результат:

```
num  user  time        link count
1    b     02:15:24    /vk  3
2    a     06:21:50    /ok  2
```

То есть получить количество строк с повторяющихся данными в ячейке “link” и добавить столбец с последнем по времени пользователем и самим временем. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Изучите пожалуйста использование `COUNT` вместе с `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Acinit select link, count(*) from table group by link , к примеру, но как сюда прикрутить юзера и время  самые свежие?

Comment: `select link, user, max(time), count(*) from table group by link, user`

Comment: @SwaD, не решает проблемы отображения только последнего пользователя. Там оконные функции надо применять будет...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если бы нам не нужен был пользователь, хватило бы простого `group by link order by time desc`. Но такой подход не даст нам пользователя.

Поэтому, будем использовать оконные функции и подзапрос

```
select * From (
  select 
    row_number() over (partition by link order by time desc),
    link,
    count(*) over (partition by link),
    last_value(sUser) over (partition by link order by tTime) as user
  from log) t
where t.row_number=1
```

`row_number` нужен для того, чтобы оставить последнюю по времени запись. `count(*) over (partition by link)` - чтобы посчитать общее количество в разрезе ссылок. `last_value(sUser) over (partition by link order by tTime)` - даст последнего пользователя в разрезе ссылок

[фиддл](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a32069/4)

Comment: Можно упростить и вместо ``last_value(sUser) over (partition by link order by tTime) as user`` взять ``sUser``. По условию ``t.row_number=1`` оно же и получится.